# Confusion from textbook about the internal electric field being 0 within a closed conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

I am wondering if I have misunderstood something. If the electric field within a closed conducting surface is supposed to be 0 why are there electric field lines drawn in this example inside the conductor?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbook is describing a *hollow* metal sphere (the spherical shell). The field lines are drawn only in the empty space inside the sphere and not within the conductive shell.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I feel very silly but I am glad I asked (and glad you answered!). I would have come into real difficulty otherwise later on!

Answer (score 3):

When we say that electric field inside a conductor is zero, we mean that the electric field *at points that lie on the conductor* is zero. In this current context of a spherical shell, this means that the electric field at every point inside the blue region is zero. It is not necessary for the electric field inside the hollow region (i.e. the white region in which the charge resides) to be zero.

To understand why this is the case, the statement that "electric field inside a conductor is zero" is essentially stating that at equilibrium, the mobile charges inside the conductor must not experience any net force. This means that we are only concerned with the electric field at positions that lie on parts of the conductor's material itself - not the hollow cavities within the conductor.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I really misunderstood this. I really appreciate you clearing this up before I got into all sorts of problems further down the line!

Comment: @MarinaCalder glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, you will see that the electric field lines discontinue at the border between the inside of the  shell and continue outside of it, from the outside surface of the conductor.

That is, the electric field inside a conductor is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there was an initial misunderstanding about "electric field inside a hollow conducting shell" and not actually inside a conductive material of the shell.

That can happen because we are normally told that (1) inside hollow conductors and (2) conducting materials the electric field is zero.

(1)  is true only then the source of the field is outside the hollow conductor (Faraday cage effect). But this is not true of course if the field source is inside the hollow conductor like in the picture. I.e. shielding works only one way.

(2) Also saying that electric field is always zero inside a conductor's material is not correct. It is only true for a stationary case (electrostatic). If this was always true, the electric currents won't exist. And also the charge separation inside the conductor could not happen, which is actually why the electric field inside the conductors is eventually becomes zero (in the electrostatic case shown above)